# Condition a <div> to appear in ASP.NET from a List

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a list full of categories, but i just want that the ones which are "featured" to appear. This is my code:

```
<div class="categories">
     <% for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++){ %>
     <% var categorias = lista[i]; %>
     <div id="cats"><a id="categoriaBtn" href="#" title="button"><%= categorias.Name %></a></div>
                    <%} %>
</div>
```

This generates a list that shows all of the categories names, but I am implementing a "Featured Categories" option, so i want to skip the ones that have this boolean option as false:

```
categorias.Featured == false
```

I tried something like this:

```
<div class="categories">
     <% for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++){ %>
          <% var categorias = lista[i]; %>
          <% if (categorias.Featured == true){ %>
                <div id="cats"><a id="categoriaBtn" href="#" title="button"><%= categorias.Name%></a></div>
                <br />
          <%}
     else{
           this.Visible = false;
         }
     } %>
</div>
```

While writing this I could make it work, but I think there is something wrong in it. I want to make sure there are no problems with it before publishing the change.

Comment: could you upload your lista's source code ?

Comment: Your code is extremely PHPish. Have you considered either switching to Razor pages or using Web Controls?

Comment: Are you facing any problems with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has a fundamental problem.  You are giving multiple html elements the same id.  Each  one should be unique.  I'd do something like this:

```
<div class="categories">
     <% for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++){ %>
          <% var categorias = lista[i]; %>
          <% if (categorias.Featured == true){ %>
                <div id="cats<%=i%>"><a id="categoriaBtn<%=i%>" href="#" title="button"><%= categorias.Name%></a></div>
                <br />
          <%}
     } %>
</div>
```